# Whole pipeline stalls while flushing USB flash drive

Tags: pipe, io

I am executing following pipeline:
`tar -c directory | pv -T -c -B 2G | gzip -c9 | pv -T -c -B 2G | split -b 1G - /mnt/usbStick/f.tar.gz_`

The idea is to gzip a >4GB directory onto a large FAT32-formatted (reliably supports only <2GB files) USB stick.
`split` just cuts a `.gz` into 1GB pieces.

`pv` is used as pipe buffer (2GB each), mainly to prevent `gzip` throttling when it stumbles upon poorly compressible data and outputs compressed data faster than USB stick can write it.

### The problem:

When yet another 1GB part is finished, `split` flushes and closes the file. It does not start writing next part until flush is complete, so it stops accepting input.

I'd expect the second 2GB buffer to start filling up at this point, **but instead everything stops**. System is far from dead overall, but `gzip` stops using CPU and even `pv` stops updating its output. <s>From the latter part I conclude that all IO is stalled, even pipes. (Prove me wrong if I am.)</s> (I was wrong, just that specific pipeline stalled.)

So the question is, why it works this way and how to fix it.

**Edit**
It really was `pv`'s fault, `buffer` works fine. Build included in Ubuntu 16.04 can use only up to 2048 blocks up to 512KB each (`buffer -m 1024m -s 512k`), but they can be daisy-chained to form larger buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `pv` is just a monitoring tool, I guess it's a single-threaded program which uses synchronous IO. Given input and output running at different rates, it will fill and empty its buffer to prevent throttling, but if one of the pipes is completely stalled (in your case it's `split` not accepting input), the second `pv` instance will stall in the `write` call just as well. Then `gzip` will try to output more data, overflow the pipe buffer and also stall, and so on until the whole pipeline is stalled.

Try using [`buffer`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/buffer) instead of `pv` and see if that helps. `buffer` spawns two processes (one for input and one for output), and should keep the pipeline running even if the output is completely stalled.

Comment: Thanks. `buffer` works as expected. Actually, I tried it before `pv`, but it complained about too many blocks, too large buffer, etc., so I concluded that it was too ancient and so I gave up on it.